# How can I register for this Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

Whenever I long tap on a String in my device I get the "copy paste action bar". There is a "share" button on the action bar with many applications that are registered for this.

My question is how do I register for this Intent and how do I retrieve the string that is selected?

I tried this with no success...

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Here is the screenshot of the action bar circled is the "share" button I want to register for.

[image: copy paste action bar]

Comment: Please provide the **complete** `<intent-filter>` that you tried, not just one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android.intent.action.SEND` and `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`. You then retrieve the text via the `EXTRA_TEXT` extra on the `Intent` you retrieve via `getIntent()` in your activity, as is described in [the `ACTION_SEND` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks is there anyway I can also have this activity run on launch?<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

Comment: @user1163234: Have two `<intent-filter>` elements for the `<activity>`, one for each type of `Intent`.

Comment: Thx! I have another problem regarding this....Can you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142276/getintent-getstringextraintent-extra-text-has-same-result/22142959?noredirect=1#22142959