# getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT) has same result

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Activity with the following `Intent-Filter`

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.extratexttest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And I am retrieving the String like this from an Intent :

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT))
    {
        String strResult = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        Log.i("", "Received String : " + strResult);

    }
```

The first time I run the app it works great and I receive the value. However, the next time I do the same action on a different string I get the same result. It seems like its caching the result somewhere. How do I clear the cache?

Edit: This only happens when I go back thru the button "recent task button"...When I press the back button it works great...

Comment: weird, i never heard of extras being cached. care to show how you launch the intent/activity?

Comment: You should add checks for intent actions, then the caching shouldn't be a problem

Comment: What do you mean by "checks"?

Comment: Can you please provide how you fire the intent?

Comment: This only happens when I go back thru the button "recent task button"...

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the manifest, under `android:label="@string/app_name"`

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

In the activity, override this method:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { 
    // Handle new intent here.
}
```

Comment: I didn't add the code `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the manifest.
But still working.
Please tell me, what is the function of this code?